# Почему не кешируется HTTP Method OPTIONS?

Tags: http

Разбираюсь в статье в вики за HTTP. И дошел до метода OPTIONS. Так вот там написано, что он не кешируется. Хотя я не понимаю почему... Почему не кешировать результат исследования, не так же часто изменяется REST API...

Есть идеи?

Comment: Это больше про концепцию. `GET` запрос возвращает какие-то ресурсы, а `OPTIONS` список действий, возможных над этими ресурсами.

Comment: Не понял, как это объясняет отказ от кеширования? Например для того, чтобы знать ответ на то какие можно запросы слать и выполнить их.